# Want to launch the view that exists in the views sub folder using mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

In PCL Core project I have sub folder in ViewModels folder as TestViewMdoels and in that I have a FirstViewModel.cs. And in Phone UI project I have sub folder in Views folder as TestViews and in that i have FirstView.xaml. Up on launching my windows app i need to show FirstView as start up page.

Please guide me to build the sub folders in views and viewmodels folder using mvvmcross.

Thanks
Hari

**UPDATE 1**

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel 
{ 
    private string _hello = "MvvmCross"; 
    public string Hello { 
        get { return _hello; } 
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); } 
    } 
}
```

Code in FirstView.xaml

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,79,0,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Hello}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Core project, find the file App.cs, there is the overrided method `Initialize()`, so in this method in the end add `RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.TestViewModel.FirstViewModel>();`

*if there is RegisterAppStart already exist in that method, remove it and add your one

also please look through Stuart "N+1 days of MvvmCross" lessons, here is the link to the first one - [N=0 : A first MvvmCross Application](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/04/n0-first-mvvmcross-application-n1-days.html)

In his [blog](http://slodge.blogspot.com/) you can also find the other great lessons (more then 40) about MvvmCross

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I overrided the Initialize method as you suggested. But up on running the app it is not launching the view that exists in the \Views\TestViews\FirstView.xaml.

Comment: It's crashing or launching the other view? Can you add the code of you FirstView and FirstViewModel?

Comment: +1 to that request from @choper - including code in questions help answerers :) My guess is that your View does't have a namespace matching its location - so will break  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Views/MvxPhoneViewsContainer.cs#L73 - but without code I can't be sure.

Comment: The app is compiled witout any errors, on deploying it in to windows phone it is just hanging with saying loading....
Below is the code that exist in ViewModels\TestViewMdoels\FirstViewModel.cs class

class FirstViewModel
         : MvxViewModel
    {   private string _hello = "MvvmCross";
        public string Hello
        {
            get { return _hello; }
            set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
        }
 }

Comment: And in App.cs file I have below one
 public override void Initialize()
        {   CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
            RegisterAppStart<MyNamespave.ViewModels.TestViewMdoels.FirstViewModel>();
        }
In windows phone UI project Views\TestViews\FirstView.xaml file just I am using the Hello property whih is defined in FirstViewModel.

Comment: Please update you question with the code that you provided in comments and also please add the code of FirstView

Comment: In xaml the view is pointing to the correct namespace as     x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.TestViews.FirstView". Is there anything that we configure to help the mvvmcross to search the views subfolder for the xaml files.

Comment: What about FirstView.cs?

Comment: Nothing in that, i am just using the Hello property defined in the Viewmodels. <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,79,0,0" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Hello}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>

Comment: ok, so the question then, did you inherit it from MvxPhonePage?

Comment: By default it is searching for the xaml files in the views folder.In my case the xaml files exists in the Views\TestViews\. so that it is not picking up. How can we make the search engine to pick the files from the views sub folder.

Comment: @HariKrishna.U so what the problem was?